# SqlIaaSExtension.Service broken on Azure SQL Server 2016 VM

Tags: sql-server, azure

Two month ago I deployed a new VM in Azure. I used the pre-configured "SQL Server 2016 SP1 Standard on Windows Server 2016" with 7 GB of RAM, and I chose the offered option to make backups automatically. Only other things I changed is add it to AD and put some databases (largest of ~2 GB size of backup file)

Now the server is running a service called `SqlIaaSExtension.Service` which I understand is for doing these backups as well as automated patching. You can find the services description here: [MS service description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-sql-server-agent-extension)

The problem is, it keeps on building up memory until after some weeks the SQL Server itself fails to execute larger queries. A restart of the `SqlIaaSExtension.Service` fixes the problem, but this is not at all a sustainable solution.

Does anybody know a working solution other then disabling the service and loosing the functionality altogether?

My setup (german):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have meanwhile got some Information from Microsoft:
There seems to be an error in the `SqlIaaSExtension.Service` which is known to MS and will eventually be fixed.

Workaround is:

A: If you don´t need the functionality - remove this service, as indicated in the [service description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-sql-server-agent-extension).

B: If you want to keep the functionality - restart the service periodically. Possibly automate via Task-planner.

Updated info from MS 19/07/2017: Error is identified and should be fixed in the next 7-10 Days. A mitigation is restarting the service if necessary.

Updated info from MS 31/07/2017: Error should be fixed in Version 1.2.19.0. This can be checked from the Azure Portal under "extensions" in the VM-Menu.

Comment: How can I get this fix? We are currently experiencing this issue on one of our VMs.

Comment: Try restarting, and then check the version as in my main Post.